# CSS AngularJS make a div grow dynamically when it has starting static width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to add *divs* to a section, and I want the *div* to have a static start width and to grow dynamically when I add more *divs*, How can I do  this?

This code doesn't work:

```
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <section>
    <div ng-repeat="div in divs track by $index">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>

  </section>
  <button ng-click="add()">add</button>

</body>

section {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 400px;
}
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

**Link for Plunker**:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SqGXBh9zXK2P3LCIVOPG?p=preview

Comment: css isn't enough ? min-width + width + display:block

Comment: You see in the plunker its not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is: 
for section:

```
  min-width: 450px; //min width of all blocks that inside your section
  display: inline-block; //to make width "grow" with content
```

and for square:

```
display: inline-block; //instead of float, because float makes height to 0
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/azOKubY7b371u2Pt7JbD?p=preview

//note: I moved `square` class to parent node of `ng-repeat`, but it's not necessary, you just need to add `display: inline-block;` if you want to have previous structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by also using `float:left` on the `section`:

```
section {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px 0;
  float:left;
}
```

And making the `squares` direct descendants, which will actually fill up the `section`:

```
<section>
   <div class="square"ng-repeat="div in divs track by $index"></div>
</section>
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y0Bg3B7bdkc3h9zG0IZw)